# Enum class defined in header file does not work in struct which is located in another header file?? C++

Tags: c++, struct, enums, header

**SomeHeader.h:**

```
enum class TypeEnum
{
    None = 0,
    BYTE,
    UBYTE,
    SHORT,
    USHORT
};
```

**AnotherHeader.h**

```
struct Structure
{
    TypeEnum type;
};
```

**Throws An Error:**
C3646 'type': unknown override specifier

**EDIT:**
Nobody seems to know the reason so am leaving additional info which might not be related:

1. TypeEnum has 33 Elements in my real code
2. It's located on top of the header file
3. Everything works fine in other headers
4. Other Structs In AnotherHeader.h With TypeEnum don't work as well
5. When I define TypeEnum in AnotherHeader.h it says enum class redefinition as it should
6. Changing to TypeEnum to enum instead of enum class does not work
7. Other enums don' work as well

**Code:**

SomeHeader.h:

```
enum class TypeSpec
{
    None = 0,
    BYTE,
    UBYTE,
    SHORT,
    USHORT,
    INT,
    UINT,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
    VEC2,
    VEC3,
    VEC4,
    VEC2I,
    VEC3I,
    VEC4I,
    VEC2U,
    VEC3U,
    VEC4U,
    VEC2D,
    VEC3D,
    VEC4D,
    MAT2,
    MAT3,
    MAT4,
    MAT2I,
    MAT3I,
    MAT4I,
    MAT2U,
    MAT3U,
    MAT4U,
    MAT2D,
    MAT3D,
    MAT4D
};
```

AnotherHeader.h:

```
struct BufferElement
{
    const char* name;
    TypeSpec type;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int offset;
    bool normalized;

    BufferElement() : name("none"), type(TypeSpec::None), size(0), offset(0), normalized(false) {}
    BufferElement(TypeSpec _type, const char* _name, bool _normalized = false) :
        name(_name), type(_type), size(RenderCommand::getTypeComponentCount(type)), offset(0), normalized(_normalized) {}
};
```

Comment: Are you including the other header file in this one?

Comment: When i define enum class in AnotherHeader.h it works fine ofcourse, but whats wrong with this?

Comment: Maybe in AnotherHeader.h you can add at the beggining:  #include "SomeHeader.h"

Comment: I did that already nothing happens

Comment: yes, am including it

Comment: idk, other enum classes works fine in other headers

Comment: Is the missing semicolon after the definition of `TypeEnum` in your actual code or was that a transcription error for this question?

Comment: oh, sorry forgot. it's correct in code.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I can't reproduce this. Presumably in the actual code there's some stray error that's different from all the other enum classes you have, but it's impossible to spot it from this representation.

Comment: I will add the code, but it's bit long.

Comment: Can you edit the example until it's _minimal_ and reproducible? For instance, if you take out the second constructor, do you still get the problem? Because I have no idea what `RenderCommand::getTypeComponentCount(type)` is and have no idea if that's relevant to the problem.

Comment: It just switches TypeEnum and converts it to OpenGL Type, Nothing Special, it works without it. I tried doing everything, but it does not works in specificly this class and class is pretty small it self and there is nothing suspicous going, i checked everything not sure what it can be, i will keep debugging and find the answer, i don't think you can help, if error was not some kind of typo i will answer my question, otherwise i will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've given us all of AnotherHeader.h, where is the include?

```
#include "SomeHeader.h"
```

We do this ALL THE TIME. It's trivial. Define something in one header and #include it at the top of anywhere else you need it. Oh, you should also do this at the top of all .h files:

```
#pragma once
```

This keeps the file from being included more than once. (It ignores multiple appearances.)

So your entire SomeHeader would look like:

```
#pragma once

#include "SomeHeader.h"

struct BufferElement
{
    TypeEnum type;
};
```

Assuming you aren't doing weird stuff with namespaces you haven't actually shown us.